# Get (row,col) indices of max value in dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, max, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[5, 7, 10], [7, 20, 4,], [8, 1, 6,]]
cities = ['Boston', 'Phoenix', 'New York']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cities, index=cities)
```

Output:

```
         Boston  Phoenix   New York
Boston      5       7         10
Phoenix     7       20         4
New York    8       1          6
```

And I want to be able to find the city pair with the greatest value. In this case I would want to return Phoenix,Phoenix.

I have tried:

```
cityMax = df.values.max()
cityPairs = df.idxmax()
```

The first one only gives me the largest value (20) and the second gives me each cities max pair not just the overall max. Is there a way to return the index and column header for a specified value in a dataframe?

Comment: Related: [Return list of indices/index where a min/max value occurs in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333402/return-list-of-indices-index-where-a-min-max-value-occurs-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unstack() and extract the top MultiIndex as a tuple using idxmax()

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[5, 7, 10], [7, 20, 4,], [8, 1, 6,]]
cities = ['Boston', 'Phoenix', 'New York']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cities, index=cities)

print df.unstack().idxmax()
```

returns:

```
('Phoenix', 'Phoenix')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this too

```
In [15]: df_mat = df.as_matrix()

In [16]: cols, idxs = np.where(df_mat == np.amax(df_mat))

In [17]: ([df.columns[col] for col in cols], [df.index[idx] for idx in idxs])
Out[17]: (['Phoenix'], ['Phoenix'])
```

@piemont method seems more elegant. However, I wonder in your case (size of data), which method would work faster. Could you check that out, by timing these functions on your full data?

Answer (score 0):

```
row_city, column_city = (df.max(axis=1).idxmax(), df.max(axis=0).idxmax())
```